# How to copy node with namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml:

```
<root>
<header>dd</header>
<confirmationAcknowledgement xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" fpmlVersion="5-11" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation ../../fpml-main-5-11.xsd http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig# ../../xmldsig-core-schema.xsd">
<header>
    <messageId messageIdScheme="http://www.partyA.com/coding-scheme/message-id">234234923420</messageId>
    <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="http://www.partyA.com/coding-scheme/message-id">234234923419</inReplyTo>
    <sentBy messageAddressScheme="http://www.partyA.com/coding-scheme/party-id">ABC123</sentBy>
    <sendTo messageAddressScheme="http://www.partyA.com/coding-scheme/party-id">ABC456</sendTo>
    <creationTimestamp>2000-08-01T08:57:00-00:00</creationTimestamp>
</header>
<correlationId correlationIdScheme="http://www.example.com/conversationId">CORR/2000/08/01/234234923120</correlationId>
<sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
```

I'd like to only copy the the confirmationAcknowledgement as it is.

What I've tried?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/root/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="confirmationAcknowledgement/@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: "Not working" isn't a good description of the problem. Tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to only copy the the confirmationAcknowledgement as it is.

To copy the `confirmationAcknowledgement` element "as it is" - including all its attributes and child nodes, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ns0:confirmationAcknowledgement"/>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy-of select="confirmationAcknowledgement" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation"/>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked, but can you please explain why this wouldn't work without a namespace prefix?

Comment: Without a prefix that is bound to the same namespace that `confirmationAcknowledgement` is in, the processor would be looking for an element named `confirmationAcknowledgement` in no-namespace - and find nothing. Alternatively, you could declare `"http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation"` as [xpath-default-namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames)- see the addition to my answer.